# Is it possible to deserialize an object in C#, that has been binary serialized in C++ MFC?

Tags: c#, c++, serialization, mfc, binary

The object has been serialized in C++ MFC using the `CObject::Serialize()` Method.

I would like to deserialize in C#.

Is that possible at all?

Comment: Did you mean to say 'I would like to deserialize in C++'?

Comment: I think he meant to say "The object has been serialized in *C++* MFC".

Comment: Sorry, edited my mistake, now it's right

Comment: Everything is possible, but you probably won't be able to use the standard C# deserialization facilities. You will have to decode the binary stream yourself.

Comment: Not necessarily, because the binary format of CObject::Serialize() is not open afaik.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is that possible at all?

Short answer: No.

MFC's de-serialization produces unmanaged objects on the unmanaged heap, and it needs access to the respective class' [CRuntimeClass](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cyfc5et8.aspx), as well as the framework's global structure mapping class names to factory methods. The latter, in particular, are not accessible from C#.

What you can do is read the serialized binary stream, and reconstruct the information to be stored in managed objects. The binary file format is documented under [TN002: Persistent Object Data Format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/32wxt301.aspx)<sup>1)</sup>. This will not allow you to serialize those managed objects back to an MFC-compatible binary stream (unless you re-implement the file format in your managed classes as well).

---

<sup>1)</sup> *Note: The binary representation of each object in the serialized stream is encoded in its class' [CObject::Serialize](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ct517hs4.aspx) override. Knowing the overall file format is not enough to de-serialize an MFC-serialized stream. You also need to know each object's serialization code.*

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible...

However, whether or not you'd want to do it is another thing. The MFC serialization format is geared towards the MFC framework. It encodes the names of MFC classes into the serialized data that you'd have to try find an equivilant C++ class for.

Your best bet would be to use a language agnostic serialization format and use that to serialize your data. JSON, XML or [Protobuf](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/) are good fits for this.

Comment: *"Yes, it's possible..."* - Ok, I'll bite. How? Even a rough sketch would be enough.

Comment: @IInspectable - you'd have to reverse engineer the MFC serialization format and provide mappings on types from C++ to C#. For example you'd map `CString` to `string`, `CArray` to `List` etc etc. It won't be easy or pretty, and moving to a language agnostic format will be easier!

Comment: Well, no. You do not have to reverse-engineer the file format. It's documented. So that's the easy part, and that only gets you to the point, where you understand the container. You still don't know what to make of the contents. In other words: You may not even know that you are dealing with a `CString` or `CArray`, to perform the trivial mapping. (Btw. you'd have the same issues when using XML.) If that's all you have to offer, then your introductory punch line should be: *"No, not really..."*

Comment: could you please outline how I should about reading MFC file in C# when I have c++ source code? I have the file opened in HxD Hex Editor and I'm kinda making sense but not really..